# Atlassian Bamboo - Batch File Syntax

Tags: batch-file, bamboo

I am trying to set a variable in CI for MSBuild Script task of interpreter "Shell" configuration based on certain conditions.

First I set to initialize -

```
set BUILDCONFIG=Release
```

Then it changes as per below condition, which works properly -

```
if ${bamboo.IsReleaseBuild}==0 set BUILDCONFIG=%DebugBuildConfig%
```

Now, If I add another condition -

```
if((${bamboo.IsRCBuild}==1) AND (${bamboo.isMasterBuild}==0)) set BUILDCONFIG=%RCBuildConfig%
```

The build configuration doesn't get set as per the variable RCBuildConfig

The logs show -

> if ((1==1) AND (0==0)) set BUILDCONFIG=ProductionRelease

The bamboo variables are resolving but it's not working as per condition, I think I am making any syntactical error.

I tried,

```
if((${bamboo.IsRCBuild} EQU 1) AND (${bamboo.isMasterBuild} EQU 0)) set BUILDCONFIG=%RCBuildConfig%
if((${bamboo.IsRCBuild} EQU 1) AND (${bamboo.isMasterBuild} EQU 0)) (set BUILDCONFIG=%RCBuildConfig%)
if ((${bamboo.IsRCBuild} EQU 1) AND (${bamboo.isMasterBuild} EQU 0)) (set BUILDCONFIG=%RCBuildConfig%)
```

But none of them work. It shows

> if ((1 EQU 1) AND (0 EQU 0)) set BUILDCONFIG=ProductionRelease

Need a quick fix for it.

Thanks!

Comment: If this is Batch/cmd, `if` doesn't support logical operators or grouping. The correct syntax for an AND would be `if "a" == "a" if "b" == "b" echo yep`

Comment: @Stephan Thank you, I constructed it that way and it worked.